# gnome-control-center won't load in Ubuntu 20

Tags: 20.04, symbolic-link, gnome-control-center

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, my gnome-control-center no longer loads due to a symbol lookup error:

```
$ gnome-control-center
gnome-control-center: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: opj_image_data_alloc
```

I tried both

```
$ sudo apt purge gnome-control-center
$ sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

```
$ sudo apt purge libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
$ sudo apt install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
```

I still get the same error. How do I fix the undefined symbol error and get gnome-control-center to run?

**EDIT 01**

```
$ apt-cache policy libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
```

gives

```
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:
  Installed: 2.32.0-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Candidate: 2.32.0-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.32.0-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.28.1-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

and

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37 | grep local
```

gives

```
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007fd5caa97000)
    libopenjp2.so.7 => /usr/local/lib/libopenjp2.so.7 (0x00007fd5ca10c000)
```

**EDIT 02**

I've put the contents of my .crash file in a pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/CBf1xHVq). Any help interpreting this data for a solution is appreciated.

Comment: @user535733 I was asked about reporting a system error after upgrading Ubuntu initially. Now after a few reboots, I don't get asked anymore.

Comment: Look in /var/crash for a .crash file (perhaps more than one) corresponding to your issue.

Comment: I see multiple instances of:

"/usr/libexec/goa-daemon: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: opj_image_data_alloc"

and:

"/usr/libexec/evolution-data-server/evolution-alarm-notify: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: opj_image_data_alloc"

Comment: Open one and read it. It explains the problem in technical detail.

Comment: I think you mean open the .crash file? I see multiple errors related to libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37 and the undefined symbol: opj_image_data_alloc. Almost all of the errors deal with 
`org.gnome.OnlineAccounts: /usr/libexec/goa-daemon`

Comment: If you are saying that you do not understand the crash file, or that you need help understanding a solution from the data in the crash file, then 1) Put the contents of the crash file into a pastebin, 2) Edit your question to explain what you want, and 3) Post the link to the pastebin. Comments are only intended to help lead you toward an answerable question. Summaries are generally worthless -- if you need specific help, we need to see the real output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove local libraries

```
sudo rm -v /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0
sudo rm -v /usr/local/lib/libopenjp2.so.7
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but with a "samba" related .so on Ubuntu 23.04 to 23.10 upgrade, and needed both rm followed by install of the package that contains the file:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libldbsamba-samba4.so.0
sudo apt install samba-libs
```